# F# inlining method call to reduce instructions

Tags: f#

I'm trying to see if I can wrap an array and use Units of Measure to check the indexing. The goal is to produce equivalent assembly to just using a raw array but with the added guarantees. This is where I started.

```
type Arr<[<Measure>] 'Measure, 'Value> (values: array<'Value>) =

    member _.Item 
        with get (idx: int<'Measure>) =
            values.[int idx]

    member _.Length = FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'Measure> values.Length

[<Measure>] type ItemIdx


let test1 (x: array<float>) =
    let mutable acc = 0.0
    let mutable idx = 0
    let len = x.Length

    while idx < len do
        acc <- acc + x.[idx]

    acc

let test2 (x: Arr<ItemIdx, float>) =
    let mutable acc = 0.0
    let mutable idx = 0<ItemIdx>
    let len = x.Length

    while idx < len do
        acc <- acc + x.[idx]

    acc
```

`test1` produces this assembly

```
; Core CLR 6.0.21.52210 on amd64

_.test1(System.Double[])
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
    L0007: mov eax, [rcx+8]
    L000a: test eax, eax
    L000c: jle short L0015
    L000e: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rcx+0x10]
    L0013: jmp short L000a
    L0015: ret
```

`test2` produces this assembly

```
; Core CLR 6.0.21.52210 on amd64

_.test2(Arr`1<System.Double>)
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0004: vzeroupper
    L0007: vxorps xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
    L000c: mov rax, [rcx+8]
    L0010: mov edx, [rax+8]
    L0013: nop [rax+rax]
    L0018: nop [rax+rax]
    L0020: test edx, edx
    L0022: jle short L0034
    L0024: mov rcx, rax
    L0027: cmp dword ptr [rcx+8], 0
    L002b: jbe short L0039
    L002d: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rcx+0x10]
    L0032: jmp short L0020
    L0034: add rsp, 0x28
    L0038: ret
    L0039: call 0x00007ffd109ee750
    L003e: int3
```

`test2` is much more verbose. I tried adding the `[<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)>]` attribute to `member _.Item` and it gave an error saying that "This attribute is not valid for this language element".

```
    [<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)>] // <-- Compiler says NO
    member _.Item 
        with get (idx: int<'Measure>) =
            values.[int idx]
```

I also tried just using the inline keyword like so:

```
    member inline _.Item // <-- Again, compiler says NO
        with get (idx: int<'Measure>) =
            values.[int idx]
```

The compiler reports an error that `The value 'Item' was marked inline, but its implementation makes use of an internal or provate function which is not sufficiently accesible`

Is there anyway to inline this method call so that I can get equivalent assembly?

**Update**

I have figured out that to `inline` a method you cannot be using private members. I changed the implementation of `Arr<'Measure, 'Value>` to this:

```
type Arr<[<Measure>] 'Measure, 'Value> (values: array<'Value>) =

    member _.Values = values

    member inline this.Item 
        with get (idx: int<'Measure>) =
            this.Values.[int idx]

    member _.Length = FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'Measure> values.Length
```

But I still get the same assembly on the other end.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: " use Units of Measure to check the indexing" - I'm trying to get my head around that. Can you elaborate?